# Hamming Numbers code not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the first 10 hamming numbers (numbers whose prime factors are 2, 3 and 5). The first `getFactors(num)` function returns what I want (a `set` of the prime factors), however the second `hammingNum()` function doesn't run as desired. Any ideas?

```
    let factors = []
        isPrime = true


    function getFactors(num){   

        while (num % 2 === 0){
            factors.push(2);
            num /= 2;
        } 

        for (i = 3; i < num; i++){
            if (num % i === 0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } else {
                isPrime = true
            }
        } 

        if (isPrime){
            factors.push (num)
        }

        if (!isPrime) {
            factors.push (i)
            getFactors (num/i)
        }

        return new Set (factors) //return a set of prime numbers     
    } 


    function hammingNums(){
        let list = []

        while (list.length < 11){
            for (i = 1; i<1000; i++){

                if ((getFactors (i)).has (2 && 3 && 5)){
                    list.push (i)
                } 
            } 
        } return list

    hammingNums()
```

Comment: what is `2 && 3 && 5` supposed to do? logical AND return `5`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you are passing `2 && 3 && 5 === 5` into the `has` method.

How about this?

```
var s = getFactors(i);
if(s.has(2) && s.has(3) && s.has(5)) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cause of the issue:

```
if ((getFactors (i)).has (2 && 3 && 5)) {/* ... */}
```

You have to list out each condition explicitly:

```
if (getFactors(i).has(2) && getFactors(i).has(3) && getFactors(i).has(5)) {/* ... */}
```

Since it looks like `getFactors` is a potentially expensive call, you should only perform it once, then store the result and use that:

```
const factors = getFactors(i);
if (factors.has(2) && factors.has(3) && factors.has(5)) {/* ... */}
```

And finally, you can shorten that condition a little bit (if you want) by using the array `.every` method:

```
const factors = getFactors(i);
if ([2, 3, 5].every(n => factors.has(n))) {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I adjusted the code to your recommendation (not including the shortened version), but when I run it, it's stuck on an infinite loop. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm guessing that your `getFactors` function isn't working right either. My suspicion is that it always returns an empty set, which means nothing is ever pushed into the `list` array, which means `list.length < 11` is always true (so infinite loop).

Comment: Get `getFactors` function does work correctly, it returns a set of prime factors.